# Extracting nested elements from an XML using Qt C++

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I have an XML file with music albums that looks like this:

[image]

I want to extract the elements from the XML using Qt C++. Now I know how to extract the Author, or the Genre for example, which would be to get a `QDomNodeList` of a certain tag, then a `QDomNode` from that list at a certain index, and then converting that node to an element, and reading its attributes.

What I don't know is how do I extract the Songs? I have tried getting a `QDomNodeList` with `elementsByTagName("Songs")` from the root element, which gives me a node list of all the `<Songs>` in the XML, but then I can't again get a `QDomNodeList` of the `<Song>` tag, because it throws a conversion error.

Comment: I would not be surprise if `QDom*` classes disappear someday ([See here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtxml-index.html)) Anything against `QXmlStreamReader`?

Comment: You can follow https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtxml-streambookmarks-example.html